# How to set IPV4 address disabled in Ubuntu 20.04 using netplan?

Tags: network-manager, netplan, ipv4

I am trying to set IPV4 address as disabled. but it is setting a link-local address. Here is my config.yaml. If i apply netplan apply, link-local ipv4 address is set for the connection with ipv4 method as link-local

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager
ethernets:
    conn1:
        match:
           name: eth2
        link-local: [ ]
        dhcp4: no
```

**Expected behavior:** link-local IP should not be set when link-local: [ ] is added to config.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mess around with `.yaml` files, you could just disable the method.

0. Open Terminal
1. Get a list of active connections:

```
$ nmcli connection show --active
```

The output will look something like:

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE    
Wired connection 1  f885be93-d87f-3c28-ab66-4f49b8ba2408  ethernet  enp0s31f6 
docker0             9985de00-2ab1-4dc2-930c-bca3a93d1f25  bridge    docker0
```

2. Take the `UUID` of the connection you want to be IPv6 only and disable the unnecessary method:

```
$ nmcli connection modify f885be93-d87f-3c28-ab66-4f49b8ba2408 ipv4.method disabled
```

3. Restart networking:

```
$ nmcli networking off
$ nmcli networking on
```

That connection will always use IPv6 until told otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @Matigo . I am looking for a way to do this via .YAML file. Through YAML, it works well for IPV6 and not IPV4